# Raphael.js onclick event

Tags: javascript, button, svg, raphael

I am trying to make some simple buttons on Raphael.js.
So I stuck in the last step.
Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coffeecupdrummer/6JVZK/)
So my buttons keep the active state after you press them. 
But I trying to make pressed button 
inactive, when I press another.

I was trying to get st.node.state value with the loop inside the onclick function
but it's just not working for me.
Here is my code:

```
for(var i in aus) {

    (function (st) {

        st.node.state = 0;



        st.node.onmouseover = function() {
            st.animate({fill: "#8fbf27", stroke: "#fff"}, 100);
        };
        st.node.onmouseout = function() {
            st.animate({fill: "#555", stroke: "#fff"}, 100);
            if(this.state == 1){
                st.animate({fill: "#fff", stroke: "#fff"}, 100);
            }else {
                st.animate({fill: "#555", stroke: "#fff"}, 100);
            }
        };
        st.node.onclick = function() {

            if(this.state == 0) {
                this.state = 1;
                st.animate({fill: "#fff", stroke: "#fff"}, 100);
            }else {
                this.state = 0;
                st.animate({fill: "#555", stroke: "#fff"}, 100);
            }

        };

    })(aus[i]);
```

Comment: Is all that happening in the click event?

Comment: I don't see the part where you're looping to try to deactivate all the other nodes.  I waw wondering if you were doing all this inside an onclick handler.

Comment: I didn't put it in here.. Because It wasn't working at all. And it didn't look good:) This buttons suppose to be so easy to make but I really stuck on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work.  This lets the elements animate themselves based on state.  On click, if the element is being activated, loop through and deactivate the others.

```
// An animator function which will animate based on node state
var animate = function(st) {
  var fill = st.node.state ? "#fff" : "#555";
  st.animate({fill: fill, stroke: "#fff"}, 100);
}

for (i in aus) {
  (function (st) {
    st.node.state = 0;
    st.node.onmouseover = function () {
      if (!this.state) st.animate({fill: "#8fbf27", stroke: "#fff"}, 100);
    };
    st.node.onmouseout = function () {
      animate(st);
    };
    st.node.onclick = function () {
      this.state = 1 - this.state;
      animate(st);
      // if the node is deactivated stop now
      if (!this.state) return;
      // otherwise deactivate and animate the other nodes
      for (i in aus) {
        // if node is `this` or node is already deactivated, continue
        if (aus[i].node === this || !aus[i].node.state) continue;
        // otherwise deactivate and animate
        aus[i].node.state = 0;
        animate(aus[i]);
      }
    };
  }(aus[i]));
}
```

Alternatively, if only one is activated at a time, you might just store a reference to the one activated node and avoid looping.

```
// A reference to the active element
var activeEl;

// animate based on whether the st is the active element
var animate = function(st) {
  var fill = activeEl === st ? "#fff" : "#555";
  st.animate({fill: fill, stroke: "#fff"}, 100);
}

for (i in aus) {
  (function (st) {
    st.node.onmouseover = function () {
      if (!this.state) st.animate({fill: "#8fbf27", stroke: "#fff"}, 100);
    };
    st.node.onmouseout = function () {
      animate(st);
    };
    st.node.onclick = function () {
      if (!activeEl || activeEl !== st) {
        var el = activeEl;
        activeEl = st;
        if (el) animate(el);
      } else {
        activeEl = null;
      }
      animate(st);
    };
  }(aus[i]));
}
```

Comment: Looks good. I'm now trying to run it, but I get odd behavior have a look - http://jsfiddle.net/coffeecupdrummer/cYKW6/

Comment: That was odd.  Turns out I had a typo with the hex color, instead of `#8fbf27` I wrote `#8fb27`, which is invalid.  For some reason this apparently caused some craziness in Raphael, making the node animate to black then fire the mouseout, and repeat.  Fixed it here: http://jsfiddle.net/cYKW6/5/

Comment: And if it's not difficult to you can you give me an idea how to make one button always pressed. Like a default state.

Comment: I mean kind of a radio buttons behavior, when one button is pressed as default. Basically you cannot turn one button On and then Off again. To turn it Off you need to press another. Like a switch) So all buttons cannot have state of 0 at one time.

Comment: New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cYKW6/6/  Instead of toggling state the onclick just returns if state is 1.  After the loop activate and animate the default.

Comment: It's much easier to study when someone can help you! I really appreciate your help. Thanks again)